# Angular: Link environment.ts as a separate JS file in index.html

Tags: angular, deployment, build

By default, Angular is configured to link the environment.ts file into main.js during build. So when having multiple environments (and so multiple environment.ts files), we need to decide for the environment during build time.

What I want is

- building only one time (production mode)
- deploying to multiple environments

So wouldn't it be a good idea to include the environment.ts(js) as a separate script in index.html and replace the file AFTER build time BEFORE deployment (as part of a Jenkins pipeline for example)?

And, how to do so? Did anyone configure an angular project this way?

What I currently have is the hint to insert a script into angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
{
  "bundleName": "environment",
  "inject": true,
  "input": "src/environments/environment.ts"
}]
```

But I would need to configure a script for each environment, because wildcards are not allowed here. Maybe I should use tsc independently from `ng b`?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do this based on [this article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1338/build-your-angular-app-once-deploy-anywhere).

The basic idea is to not use `environment.{env}.ts` file, define a custom configuration file which is available in the SPA without being merged in the main.js file.

I have followed the following steps:

- added the configuration file in `src\config`. This is a copy of the environment.ts
- removed everything from the `environment.ts` files, except for the production property
- defined a TS interface (e.g. AppConfig) to store current configuration values
- defined a ConfigService to actually load the configuration data
- load the configuration at application startup. Some services will require explicit dependency on ConfigService to properly work:

```
const appInitializerFn = (configService: ConfigService) => {
  return () => {
    return configService.setConfig();
  };
};

ConfigService,
{
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: appInitializerFn,
    multi: true,
deps: [ConfigService]
},

// all services (or similar objects) must explicitly state the dependency on ConfigService because configuration reading is done async and the service might need the values sooner than the Promise is resolved.
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BaseUrlInterceptor, multi: true, deps: [ConfigService]},
```

- some app initialization-related services will require some changes (e.g. MSAL)

All the code is available inside this [Software Codidact](https://software.codidact.com/posts/287613#answer-287614) answer.